# ReactJS semantic ui Loader: how to toggle active

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui, loader

I have the following loader (`active` is commented because by default the loader must not be seen):

```
import React from 'react'
import { Dimmer, Loader, Segment } from 'semantic-ui-react'

const DefaultLoader = () => (
  <Segment>
    <Dimmer
        //active
        page={true}>
      <Loader />
    </Dimmer>
  </Segment>
)

export default DefaultLoader;
```

I am not sure about how I can change the `active` prop when needed. I have the component loaded like this:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div className='Lesson-editor'>

      <DefaultLoader />

      ...
      ...

    </div>
  );
}
```

I would like to show the loader before this function completes:

```
const lessonID = await ARSaveLesson(lesson, sectionsToDB);
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set a active state and pass it as props to make your loader active or inactive.

```
const DefaultLoader = (props) => (
  <Segment>
    <Dimmer
        active = {props.active}
        page={true}>
      <Loader />
    </Dimmer>
  </Segment>
)
```

Maintain a state for active,

```
state = {active:false}
```

and pass this state to `DefaultLoader`

```
<DefaultLoader active={this.state.active} />
```

Now when you want to show loader do this,

```
this.setState({active:true})
```

To make it inactive do this,

```
this.setState({active:false})
```